# jQuery, count number of dynamicly added <li> in <ul>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of LI in a UL, they are all dynamically added via jQuery. I am trying to alert the number of LI in this list. Right now I can only get it to alert 0. I think it is because its trying to count the original number on load? here is my code and fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/ts7Lwbfs/1

```
<ul id="list"> 
    <li>original</li>
</ul>

var familly = []
familly.push('<li>1</li>');
familly.push('<li>2</li>');
familly.push('<li>3</li>');
familly.push('<li>4</li>');

$('#list').prepend(familly);

$('#list').on('click', 'li', function(ev){ 
    var howMany = $('#list').length; 
    alert(howMany);
});
```

How can I get it to alert the total number of LI after they are dynamically added?

Comment: The ID doesn't match the list name of "list"... $('#list').length

Comment: Sorry I edited, now its out puting 1. the original number of li in that list

Comment: No, it's outputtting `1`, the number of `#list` elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector `$('#bet_slip')` matches an element with the ID `bet_slip`, and as ID's are unique jQuery doesn't expect there to be more than one, and as none of your elements have that ID, you get zero?

Seems like what you want is to count the number of LI's in the `#list` list

```
$('#list').on('click', 'li', function(ev){ 
    var howMany = $('#list li').length; 
    alert(howMany);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/ts7Lwbfs/3/)

Note that this counts all LI's currently present, including the one that was there originally.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to find only the count of newly added li ( excluding the original ) , you can filter the li and exclude the first one using `:not:first` expression.

```
$('#list').on('click', function(ev){ 
    var howMany = $(this).find('li:not(:first)').length; 
  alert(howMany);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/ts7Lwbfs/4/

Comment: this assumes there is only ever 1 original item.

Answer (score 1):

You can count the **total number of list items** this way:

```
$('#list').on('click', function(){ 
    var howMany = $('#list li').length; 
  alert(howMany);
});
```

To get the number of **added list items**, first capture the count of original list items before you add new ones, and then subtract the total in your function from the original count.

```
var originalCnt = $('#list li').length;
$('#list').prepend(familly);

$('#list').on('click', function(){ 
    var howMany = $('#list li').length - originalCnt; 
  alert(howMany);
});
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qsxLh92q/1/)

Comment: That would give you zero .

Comment: @DinoMyte - how so?  check out the fiddle demo.  it works fine.